# Is my technique valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have serious doubts about this, but I thought you guys might at least fix this and suggest something useful which would make this approach work. The question is to prove that $$2=2\cos(x)+x\sin(x)$$ has no solution on $(0, 2\pi)$. So

$$ 2(1-\cos(x))=x\sin(x).$$

If for some value of $x$ $LHS<RHS$, and for some other value of $x$ $LHS>RHS$, then there exists a value in between where $LHS=RHS$ (this follows from the fact that both $LHS$ and $RHS$ are continuous functions). So the min of the $LHS$ is at x=0, and it so happens that 0=0 so this is a solution, but is not in the given domain. The max of the $LHS$ is given by $pi/2$, and $2>pi/2$. Therefore, there is no solution on $(0, 2\pi)$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381962/show-that-equation-has-no-solution-in-0-2-pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the argument that the max of the LHS is $\frac \pi 2$.  The maximum value of the LHS is $4$, achieved at $x=\pi$.  Second, what does $2 \gt \frac \pi 2$ tell us?  You are trying to argue that the LHS is always greater than the RHS (except at zero) but have not justified it.